# Read alternate data streams over SMB with Linux

Tags: linux, windows, samba, alternate-data-stream

I recently did a CTF involving a file on a samba share which had a password in an alternate data stream. To read it I had to connect using Windows, but I'm curious if there's any way to read ADS from linux, either using SMBclient or another tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to do this without mounting the drive.

`smbclient -U USER //IP/Share -c 'allinfo "ADS_FILE"'` followed by `get "ADS_FILE:PASSWORD:$DATA"` downloads the file.

Comment: `$DATA` is the file data. ADS is not required here - this is what you get if you just open the file.

Comment: Well this gave me what I needed, whereas just downloading the file was empty.

Comment: I think there was a problem in the Samba configuration, but that's another subject.

Comment: The stream name is "PASSWORD" and the stream type is "$DATA". The default stream has no name and type $DATA.

Answer (score 1):

Reading Alternate Data Streams (ADS) is possible when using
[ntfs-3g](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g):

> NTFS stores all data in streams. Every file has exactly one unnamed
>   data stream and can have many named data streams. The size of a file
>   is the size of its unnamed data stream. By default, ntfs-3g will only
>   read the unnamed data stream.
>
> By using the options "streams_interface=windows", with the ntfs-3g
>   driver (not possible with lowntfs-3g), you will be able to read any
>   named data streams, simply by specifying the stream's name after a
>   colon. For example:
>
> ```
> cat some.mp3:artist
> ```
>
> Named data streams act like normal files, so you can read from them,
>   write to them and even delete them (using rm). You can list all the
>   named data streams a file has by getting the "ntfs.streams.list"
>   extended attribute.

Comment: This looks like what I need. But is it possible to use this to mount over a network?

Comment: If you can mount it using ntfs-3g, then it should work.

Comment: It didn't accept `//IP/Share` as a valid mount image